# Optimize function for multiple language support

Tags: php, sql, optimization

I have created my own multiple language support for one of my projects. I have 3 different database tables for it: `languages`, `languages_variables`, and `languages_words` (as seen below).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_name` text NOT NULL,
  `data_currency` text NOT NULL,
  `is_standard` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_note` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages_variables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_language` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_variable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

When I want to extract the specific string to the website, I'll use a function called `language()` (as seen below). `$user` in the code below gets information about the logged in user, such as the language the user have chosen.

With the function, I can simply call for the variable that are in `languages_variables` with `language('menu_about')` ( `menu_about` is just an example of a variable).

```
function language($variable) {

    global $user;


    # DATABAS (kontrollera)
    $check_language = sql("SELECT COUNT(lv.data_name)

                           FROM languages AS l
                           JOIN languages_variables AS lv

                           JOIN languages_words AS lw
                           ON l.id = lw.id_language

                           WHERE lv.data_name = :variable
                           AND lw.id_language = :idlanguage
                          ", Array('idlanguage' => ($user['id_language'] == 0 ? '1' : (int)$user['id_language']),
                                   'variable' => $variable), 'count');

    # DATABAS (räkna)
    $count_words = sql("SELECT COUNT(lw.id)
                        FROM languages_words AS lw
                        JOIN languages_variables AS lv
                        ON lw.id_variable = lv.id
                        WHERE lw.id_language = :idlanguage
                        AND lv.data_name = :variable
                       ", Array('idlanguage' => ($user['id_language'] == 0 ? '1' : (int)$user['id_language']),
                                'variable' => $variable), 'count');



    # KONTROLL
    if($check_language == 0 OR $count_words == 0) {

        return $variable;


    # KONTROLL
    } else {

        # DATABAS (hämta)
        $get_languages = sql("SELECT *,
                                     lv.data_name AS name_variable,
                                     lw.data_name AS name_translation

                              FROM languages AS l
                              JOIN languages_variables AS lv

                              JOIN languages_words AS lw
                              ON lv.id = lw.id_variable

                              WHERE lv.data_name = :variable
                              AND lw.id_language = :idlanguage
                             ", Array('variable' => $variable,
                                      'idlanguage' => ($user['id_language'] == 0 ? '1' : (int)$user['id_language'])));


        # LOOP
        foreach($get_languages AS $language) {

            # KONTROLL
            if($language['name_variable'] == $variable) {
                return $language['name_translation'];

            # KONTROLL
            } else {
                return $variable;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that the website loads very slow with all the stuff that are within `language()`. Especially when I will list a lot of items from the database (for an example with a loop). The loading speed goes from under 2 seconds to under 10 seconds.

Is there another, more better and faster way to get the chosen language string?

**UPDATE** I have lower the loading speed from 7-8 seconds to 3-4 seconds. But it's still too slow.

```
function language($variable) {

    # DATABAS (hämta)
    $language = sql("SELECT lv.data_name AS name_variable,
                            lw.data_name AS name_word

                     FROM languages AS l
                     JOIN languages_variables AS lv
                     JOIN languages_words AS lw

                     ON lv.id = lw.id_variable
                     WHERE lv.data_name = :variable
                     AND l.id = :idlanguage
                    ", Array('variable' => $variable,
                             'idlanguage' => ($user['id_language'] == 0 ? '1' : (int)$user['id_language'])), 'fetch');


    return $language['name_word'];

}
```

I'm thinking of to use files (sv.php, en.php, etc.) instead of database. But then the users can't translate the website from the browser (if I do not sacrifice myself several hours of blood, sweat and tears).

Answer (score 0):

Start by profiling the build with Xhprof to validate PHP performance. For the SQL calls Google Chrome has a built-in web inspector which lets you know how long each component is taking (Firebug for Firefox).

If you post the logs it can go a long way towards suggesting relevant areas for improvement.

Comment: Thanks but I know where the problem is because I have tested to delete everything within the function `language()` and only keep `return $variable;`. The website was much more faster after that. Anyway. I did what you suggested (to see the inspector in Google Chrome) and I can only find Network and Resources than could fit what you said.

Comment: There is a commonly used add in based on: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Comment: Sorry for a slow anser. Where can I find these logs? The link you gave me only allows me to test my website - not save some logs. And what did you mention about the web inspector? Where can find to test the SQL calls and also save the logs?